# Problem with interpreting shell variables

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm trying to make a shell script where I select an option between poweroff,suspend,restart and then pass it to systemctl as in:

```
option=$(printf "poweroff\\nreboot\\nsuspend" | dmenu -p "Energy Options")

case $option in
    "poweoff")
        echo "$option" | xargs systemctl
        ;;
```

but it doesn't seen to be working out. I mean when I execute the script nothing happens, when I was expecting to shutdown my computer.

Comment: `it doesn't seen to be working`  is not a detailed description of a problem, you need to be more specific. What is contents of `$option`, what happens when you run that command, what do you expect to happen.

Comment: `poweoff` - is it a typo?

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk What do you mean by it?

Comment: It should be `poweroff` and not `poweoff`?